# create a simple ImageSlider using any of react-native libraries

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am new to React-Native and I am currently struggling out for creating a simple Image-slider in react-native. I went through some of the links like: https://reactnativeexample.com/tag/carousel/

But not able to figure out if react-native provides a library which I can import directly in my code to implement an Image-slider.
Is there a native library which I can use or is there some other procedure to create an image-slider?
I want a slider as presented in this website: https://www.jssor.com/

Answer (score 0):

For example, when you want to use react-native-snap-carousel, you can follow the instructions in the usage part of that link
https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel#usage

And also, If you want to use so simple carousel, you can use

```
<FlatList horizontal={true}/>
```